# Second page of Pagination not working in django after searching

Tags: django, templates, elasticsearch, view, pagination

Searching result is not appearing in second page what should I change to solve my problem ? and I'm using elasticsearch as search engine
index.html

```
     <ul>
                        {% for i in paginator.page_range %}
                              {% if i <= page_number|add:5 and i >= page_number|add:-5 %}

                                 <li class=" {% if i == page_number %} active {% endif %} " >
                                   <a href="?page={{forloop.counter}}">{{forloop.counter}}</a>
                                 </li>

                              {% endif %}

                        {% endfor %}
                          </ul>
```

and this is in my views.py

```
def index(request):
    q = request.GET.get('q')
    if q:
        articles = PostDocument.search().query("match", title=q, )
        paginator = Paginator(articles, 5)
        page_number = request.GET.get('page', 1)
        page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)

        return render(request, 'index.html', {
            'articles': page_obj.object_list,
            'paginator': paginator,
            'page_number': int(page_number),

        })

    else:
        articles = ''
        return render(request, 'index.html', {'articles': articles})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you write `?page=…`, then the `?q=…` parameter is "dropped". The trick is to add it to the querystring when you go to the next object:

```
def index(request):
    q = request.GET.get('q')
    if q:
        articles = PostDocument.search().query("match", title=q, )
        paginator = Paginator(articles, 5)
        page_number = request.GET.get('page', 1)
        page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)

        return render(request, 'index.html', {
            'articles': page_obj.object_list,
            'paginator': paginator,
            'page_number': int(page_number),
            'q' : q
        })

    else:
        articles = ''
        return render(request, 'index.html', {'articles': articles})
```

and then render this with:

```
<a href="?page={{ forloop.counter }}&q={{ q|urlencode }}">{{forloop.counter}}</a>
```

The [**`|urlencode`** template filter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#urlencode) is necessary to percentage encode the query, for example if it contains a question mark (`?`), ampersand (`&`), etc.